# AngularJS directive retaining original content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm totally confused on transclude/replace and directives. I thought I understood but now I'm lost on how to get this particular test case working. From everything I've in the docs, SO, and blogs, it seems like my code below should work. First, some code:

The markup:

```
<my-directive><h1>My Title</h1></my-directive>
```

The end result I want:

```
<my-directive><div class="awesome"><h1>My Title</h1></div></my-directive>
```

The directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="awesome"></div>'
  }
});
```

Instead of what I want, I get:

```
<my-directive><div class="awesome"></div></my-directive>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To place the transcluded content into the div, add the `ng-transclude` directive to it...

```
template: '<div class="awesome" ng-transclude></div>'
```

[Demo - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LmcvB/)

Comment: This works in the fiddle, not in my live code. So I'll need to do some serious debugging to figure out what the heck I'm missing.

Comment: Ugh, I had an issue on the controller for that view that was throwing a JS error. It was doing part of the directive but not all. Either way, I didn't have `ng-transclude` so I learned something!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "ng-transclude" in the directive template:

```
<div class="awesome" ng-transculde></div>
```